# A simple question for lie group

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

I know the following is wrong. But I don't see where is wrong.
Let's begin by proving $\frac{d}{dt}(A(t)\cdot B(t))=(\frac{d}{dt}A(t))\cdot B(t)+A(t)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}B(t)$, where $A(t)$, $B(t)$ are matrix lie group.

Proof:$$C(t)^i_j=A(t)^i_k\cdot B(t)^k_j,\\
\frac{d}{dt}C(t)^i_j=\frac{d}{dt}(A(t)^i_k\cdot B(t)^k_j=(\frac{d}{dt}A(t)^i_j)\cdot B^k_j+A(t)^i_k\cdot\frac{d}{dt}B(t)^k_j,\\
hence, \ \frac{d}{dt}(A(t)\cdot B(t))=(\frac{d}{dt}A(t))\cdot B(t)+A(t)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}B(t).$$
Then for $e^{tA}$, $e^{tB}$ where $A$, $B$ are two constant matrices, we should have
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{tA}\cdot e^{tB})=(\frac{d}{dt}e^{tA})\cdot e^{tB}+e^{tA}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}e^{tB}.$$
Letting $t=0$ in this equation, we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(e^{tA}\cdot e^{tB})=A+B.$$
Then it means that $A+B$ is the generator of $e^{tA}\cdot e^{tB}$. On the other hand, we know $A+B$ generates $e^{t(A+B)}$. So, (by the exponential mapping) we have $e^{tA}\cdot e^{tB}=e^{tA+tB}$ for any matrices $A$ and $B$ which is definitely wrong as known in lie group theory. What's the problem with the analysis? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why «that means» that?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you think we can jump from the second to last equation to the last equation.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez  Sorry, I will add more details soon.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have modified my question now.

Comment: That would mean that $A+B$ is a generator of $e^{tA}e^{tB}$ **if** the latter were a 1-parameter subgroup, but $t\mapsto e^{tA}e^{tB}$ is not, in general.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think $e^{tA}\cdot e^{tB}$ is a lie group and continously depends on $t$. So $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(e^{tA}\cdot e^{tB})=A+B$ should mean that $A+B$ is its generator.

Comment: Well, it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(t)=\exp(tC)$ is the $1$-parameter group generated by a matrix $C$, then $f'(t)=Cf(t)$ and $f''(t)=C^2 f(t)$, so that $$f''(0)=f'(0)^2.$$ Let us now consider the function $g(t)=\exp(tA)\exp(tB)$. We have $$g'(t)=A\exp(tA)\exp(tB)+\exp(tA)B\exp(tB)$$ and 
\begin{align}
g''(t)&=A^2\exp(tA)\exp(tB)+A\exp(tA)B\exp(tB)\\
 &+A\exp(tA)B\exp(tB)+\exp(tA)B^2\exp(tB).
\end{align} It follows that $$g'(0)=A+B$$ as you noticed and that $$g''(0)=A^2+2AB+B^2.$$ If $AB\neq BA$, then $g''(0)\neq g'(0)^2$. This tells us that in that case the function is **not** a $1$-parameter subgroup.

If instead $AB=BA$ then one can easily check that $g$ is a $1$-parameter subgroup.

Comment: Well, then, I have another question. It is stated that the commutator $e^{tA}e^{tB}e^{-tA}e^{-tB}$ has generator as $[A,B]$. However, according to the up-mentioned analysis, we have $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(e^{tA}e^{tB}e^{-tA}e^{-tB})=A+B-A-B=0$. Where is the problem hide?

Comment: That is not a 1-parameter subgroup.

Comment: If it were a 1-parameter subgroup, then since its derivative at zero is the zero matrix, then it would be constant, but it is not constant.

Comment: A good conclusion is: not all functions from $\mathbb R$ to matrices, even if they can be writtten in terms of exponentials, are 1-parameter subgroups!